# How to write Salesforce data using Apex into Google Spreadshee

Tags: oauth2, google-drive

I need to write data into Google Spreadsheet using Apex but i am not getting pointers. Can any one help me out on below points -

> 1) How to authenticate Google Account from Apex code?
>
> 2) How to create and Write data into Google Spreadsheet from Apex?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://theforcetimes.wordpress.com/tag/upload-files-from-salesforce-to-google-drive/

Comment: http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2014/05/google-drive-authentication-in.html

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47685/how-to-create-a-file-inside-a-folder-in-google-drive

Comment: also - this can be done with Conga Composer appexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://theforcetimes.wordpress.com/tag/upload-files-from-salesforce-to-google-drive/

http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2014/05/google-drive-authentication-in.html

[How to create a file inside a folder in google drive?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47685/how-to-create-a-file-inside-a-folder-in-google-drive)